# Shortcut for moving current window to another Destkop

Tags: keyboard

I have an external monitor connected to my M1 Air.

On each I have 3 desktops - D1 - D3 for macbook and d4 - d6 for the external monitor.

I switch between desktops via <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + 1 or <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + 3 up to 6.

No problem here, but ... I want to move a current program window I am working on from D6 to D3.

How do I that without <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + up and using the mouse or awkward keyboard selections?

Is there some shortcut setting like "move current window one desktop to the left" or "... right"?

Or even better, "move current window to desktop 1" and 2, 3 ... ?

Comment: To move in the same display, hold the window title bar then use your Ctr/[num] to carry it to your desired Space. I cannot test how this will work if you use 'Displays have separate Spaces'. Presumably it will bring the Space to the 'wrong' display. Can you not simply drag it from one Display to the other - assuming both have the correct 'leaving' & 'arriving' Spaces already front-most?

Comment: Keyboard shortcut please

Comment: Already explained in my first comment.

Comment: So, there are no keyboard only shortcuts, get it, thanks anyway.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To this day, there is no ONLY keyboard solution to this problem without using some 3rd party automation software and/or scripting this functionality in a programming language.